# Clip a child SPAN when it exceeds the height of the parent TD/TABLE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my outer `table`/`td` clip the inside `SPAN` when the `span` content exceeds the height of the outer table while preserving table alignment both vertically and center.

So instead of this:

[image]

I would get this:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/xstatic/nksf9r71/14/

```css
table {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 0px;
}

table td span {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><span>KITTENS DON'T ALWAYS GO TO HEAVEN</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what other requirements you have, but this will give you the output you're after:

```css
table td div {
  height: 2rem; /* Or whatever height you're after*/
}
table td div div {
  margin: -0.5rem;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

You'll have to add a wrapper div:

```html
<tr><td><div><div>KITTENS DON'T ALWAYS GO TO HEAVEN</div></div></td></tr>
```

However, this is a strange way to display a table cell. It may cause issues, down the road.

Comment: So, this is basically forcing the crop, right?  Which is not really what I am trying to accomplish.  I just want the height of the span to stay at whatever height it is, without influencing the height of the table around it.

Comment: I see. Table cells are meant to size to their content, rather than the other way around. You could force the cell to size itself to a div which acts as a wrapper for your content. I've modified the code to demonstrate. Also, I've changed the `span` to a `div`, rather than changing `display` to 'block'.

Comment: In order to align the top of your content above the top of it's container, you'll still have to alter it's `position` or `margin` (as above) from default.